# Error parsing data android with subarray

Tags: android, json

This is the JSON result of my query.

```
{
    "_id":{"$id":"551fb585ecba12c819000032"},
    "nome":"Google","loc":[-122.083983,37.422969],
    "icona":1,
    "istituzione_id":{"$id":"551fb556ecba12c819000031"}
    }
    {
    "_id":{"$id":"5520fe2becba12c003000029"},
    "nome":"Oracle","loc":[-122.262168,37.531595],
    "icona":1,
    "istituzione_id":{"$id":"551fb556ecba12c819000031"}
    }
```

I've tried to parse JSON result in this manner:

```
try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("log_a_line", line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

           is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
                    Log.e("log_a_result", result);

        } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("log_tag_convert", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
                }

        //-----PARSER----
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", "id:" + json_data.getString("_id"));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
             {
            Log.e("log_tag_parsing", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
             }
```

But after run the app, in my logcat i found error:

```
log_tag_parsing﹕ Error parsing dataorg.json.JSONException: Value {"icona":1,"loc":[-122.083983,37.422969],"nome":"Google","istituzione_id":{"$id":"551fb556ecba12c819000031"},"_id":{"$id":"551fb585ecba12c819000032"}} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I have thought that the problem was about the subarray loc:[....] maybe.

I can't reach the solution. Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma between objects; and use `[]` for arrays and `{}` for objects.

Next time use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON first.

Answer (score 0):

> org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

The answer is in your exception. You are trying to convert jsonobject to jsonArray.
Convert your result into `JsonObject`

Answer (score 0):

see here you are getting JSONObject as a result. but while parsing, you are expecting JSONArray.

Before parsing First add one check to the result.

E.g.

```
if (resultObj instanceof JSONArray) {
    // process Array
}
else if (resultObj instanceof JSONObject) {
    // processObj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Json array syntax should be like this one

employees is array name

[] // for array that contains objects {} between one object and another ,

```
"employees":[
     {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, 
     {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"}, 
     {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
 ]
```

create correct json array

EDIT

to generate array of json

```
$a = array(
        array('foo' => 'bar'),
        array('foo' => 'baz'));
$json = json_encode($a);
```

to given

```
[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]
```

read more

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: the json is generated in my  php file with this  "echo json_encode($row);"

Comment: make array and then encode it echo json_encode($arr); which arr is your array

Answer (score 0):

Why your for loop have starting value as -1 and change the Log printing line to. See code below:

```
//-----PARSER----
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {   //this line
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag", "id:" + json_data.getString("_id"));//this line
            }
        }
```

change both mentioned line to as:

```
//-----PARSER----
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {   //this line
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag", "id:" + json_data.getString("$id"));
                }
            }
```

Comment: You have to change at 2 different lines. For the Log printing line the "_id" you have to change it to "$id"